# I have a number list in a single column seperated by 'comma' delimeter and would like to have these numbers in diffrent columns in SQL

Tags: split, substring, row

mytable decimals has these grouped in on column
and I need these numbers in different columns in on row
ROW 1 (2.790809715,0.558909878,0.854724284,5.911869194,1.0,0.653906632,0.028937023,14.74713266)
ROW 2 (2.792435064,0.3959906,0.78997913,5.672903497,1.7650,0.501267134,0.01447697,13.5177037)

`your text`like for example
`your text`     ,bd.left (qualities, 11) as SG
`your text`     ,bd.substring (qualities, 13, 11)as Cu
`your text`    ,bd.substring (qualities, 25, 11)as CuS
`your text`     ,bd.substring (qualities, 37, 11)as Uppm
thus giving
SG          | Cu          | CuS         | Uppm
2.790809715 | 0.558909878 | 0.854724284 | 5.911869194

now my code only works for the first row of data and the next row only first two sets of data.

STRING_SPLIT would work but you know I have that old version of sql, so need help seen the examples but my data is all numeric so the results of trying are sql messages laughing back at me... HELP

I tried substring , triad using CHARINDEX  the the comma inside, u know that kind of stuff wanting to turn this
ROW 1 (2.790809715,0.558909878,0.854724284,5.911869194,1.0,0.653906632,0.028937023,14.74713266)
ROW 2 (2.792435064,0.3959906,0.78997913,5.672903497,1.7650,0.501267134,0.01447697,13.5177037)

into that
SG          | Cu          | CuS         | Uppm
2.790809715 | 0.558909878 | 0.854724284 | 5.911869194